# Passing Windows Identity name to server

Tags: c#, .net, windows-identity

I need to get my logged in Windows user name, from the PC I am using to the server hosting my site.

In my code I have the following line:

```
  var user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

When I run my project locally it returns what I expect: `myComputer\UserAccountName`

However, when I deploy my site to my server, it is picking up my servers username: `myServer\ServerAccountName`

What is the call that I need to make in order to correctly pass down `UserAccountName` and not have the `ServerAccountName` used instead?

Comment: Are you talking about an ASP.Net application? If so the only way for that to happen automatically is to configure [Windows Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication/) which is probably not what your looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you not use the following?

```
User.Identity.Name;
```